# Read environment variable from Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, environment-variables

Is it possible to read an environment variable from the code of a **Google Chrome extension**, that is, from [background.js](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest)? This is possible in case of **Mozilla Firefox extensions**, this way:

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
console.log(system.env.PATH);
```

What is the equivalent code in case of Chrome? The OS is Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interact with OS you have to create Windows executable and use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host) to communicate with it. Take a look at [example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/).